# differential input overvoltage protection

Tags: circuit-protection, rs485

some suggestions to protect an RS485 from differential input overvoltage?
I want protect the transceiver RS485 if the differential input voltage is below -7V or above +12V.
Someone does anyone know any device or IC that do this?

Comment: What is the impedance and peak voltage magnitude of the threat and what specifically is the victim circuit or IC?

Comment: For most applications, they make special four-Zener setups in a SOT23-3 package specifically for RS-485 that have standoff voltages at +12 and -7.  Just search "RS485 diode" and you'll find them.  But like @Andyaka says, more details will make sure you're getting the right information.

Comment: TVS diodes are made for this

Comment: You must mean single-ended voltages of -7V and +12V for each wire of the differential pair? It would not make sense to have asymmetric differential voltage protection.

Answer (score 0):

A bidirectional Zener diode with a voltage reverse stand-off of 5V and a voltage breakdown of 5V  to 6 V will do.

Digikey filter:

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/tvs-diodes/144?s=N4IgjCBcpgHAzFUBjKAzAhgGwM4FMAaEAeygG0QAWAJngFZ4A2EAXSIAcAXKEAZU4BOASwB2AcxABfIgHZGEaCFSRMuQiXIhqlAJxgZEIrWoAGE8yPx4J2DpCXrsC1viUwJyvZeU6NL9UYZHzp-QJ9qVg5uSD5BUQlpcBlrJCV0bHwiUkgKCDYQLh4ASRFOPDE8ASkiMB1bVOVVTI0ckBNIgujY4XFqkABaCMVlQQBXdWyKEJZE-oUUdLUszV0ZVkkNoA